# NaN error with parseInt()

Tags: javascript

```js
function square(num) {
      var numbers = num.split(" "),
      sq1 = numbers[0] * numbers[0],
      sq2 = numbers[1] * numbers[1];
      var result = Math.abs(sq2 - sq1);
      return parseInt(result);
}
console.log(square(3 4))
```

I'm receiving an error of `NaN`. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

```
Test Case #1
call: square(4 2);
expect: 12

Test Case #2
call: square(3 4)
Expected output: 7
```

Comment: your code is working, what is the problem with it?

Comment: You should `parseInt` before the multiplication

Comment: btw, you need not to use `parseInt` to get an integer value, just take `Math.floor`.

Comment: Also, `NaN` is not an error, it is a value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function with a string.

- Call function with string as parameter.
- `*` coerces operands to number.
- `parseInt` for geting an integer is not recommended, use `Math.floor` instead.

```js
function square(num) {
    var numbers = num.split(" "),
        sq1 = numbers[0] * numbers[0],
        sq2 = numbers[1] * numbers[1];

    return Math.abs(sq2 - sq1);
}

console.log(square('4 2')); // string with space separated numbers
console.log(square('3 4'));
```

Comment: Without passing a string he/she could not get a `NaN` value as `num.split` would throw an error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't alter the test case! It's only the function that can be edited. Instructions: It should properly output the difference between squared numbers. Inputs will be a pair of numbers, separated by a space.

Comment: @user8227859, you have not included the call of the function. you may check the type by using `console.log(typeof num)`.

Comment: @user8227859 i feel like the test case in actuality is a string. If `num.split(" ")` doesn't log an error to the console I am certain

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro, the erro must have shown earlier, because of missing `)`, like in the questestion's console shown.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you call `split` you get an array of strings. When you call

```
 sq1 = numbers[0] * numbers[0],
 sq2 = numbers[1] * numbers[1];
```

you are applying the `*` operation to strings. So when you use `parseInt()` later the string you parse is no longer a valid string representation of a number.

Call

```
sq1 = parseInt (number[0]) * parseInt (number[0]),
sq2 = parseInt (number[1]) * parseInt (number[1]);
```

(Note the unary plus operator does the same thing as parseInt if the string is not a float and would be better if floats are expected

Usage :

```
+"123.1" !== parseInt("123.1");
+"123" === parseInt("123");
```

)

And remove the `parseInt` to fix it as follows:

```
var result = Math.abs( sq1 - sq2);
```

Comment: Your final statement is incorrect. OP is trying to subtract the two values that they've squared previously

Comment: @varfirstName fixed

Answer (score 1):

> square(3 4)
> [when it should be square("3 4")]

but also, your code isn't well optimized.

Here's a good way:

```js
function square(num) {
  var numbers = num.split(" ");
  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = Math.pow(parseInt(numbers[i]),2)
  }
  var result = Math.abs(numbers[1]-numbers[0]);
  return result;
}
console.log(square('4 3'))
```

So, this keeps your function the same, but here's an even better way:

```js
function diff_Squares(num1,num2) {
    return Math.abs(Math.pow(num2,2)-Math.pow(num1,2));
}
square(2,3)
```

In this example, you can use numbers as parameters instead of strings!

### Big issue here:

`parseInt()` **only returns** `NaN` when it's input is not a number (sort of self explanatory). NaN is not an error, it's a value.

You're saying that you have to check against a test case.. is this for a coding course online or anything? If so, they might've kept your library of tools to a minimum. Like other people have said, * automatically makes strings assume the correct type so it's strange that you're receiving the wrong response (NaN).

Comment: I'm still receiving NaN as the output unfortunately. The test case is square(4 2) with and expected output of 12.

Comment: somewhere in your code, put a `console.log(typeof num)`

Comment: strange. On my computer, I'm getting 7 using your code.

Comment: I think the problem is that your call takes a string as an input and the test case doesn't?

Comment: The test input would be invalid if it did not encapsulate the two parameters...

Comment: To clarify, if the test input was not a string, you could not run the `.split` command

Comment: @user8227859 what does the test case take as input? What did `typeof num` give you?

Comment: It says it's a string when I console.log typeof num!

Answer (score 0):

I think a *better* way to achieve your goal is to **seperate the split logic from the calculate function** in your function. This will make your code **more reuseable**.

### CalculateSquare

```
function calculateSquare(a, b) {
  return Math.abs((b * b) - (a * a))
}
```

### Example

```js
function calculateSquare(a, b) {
  return Math.abs((b * b) - (a * a))
}

var numbers = '4 2'.split(' ')
var result = calculateSquare(numbers[0], numbers[1])

console.log(result)
```

### ES6 Example

```js
var numbers = '4 2'.split(' ')

function calculateSquare(a, b) {
  return Math.abs((b * b) - (a * a))
}

console.log(calculateSquare(...numbers))
```

simply in one line `calculateSquare(...'4 2'.split(' '))`

Comment: Whats the point of defining `splitString (str, del)` when you can do `str.split (del)`

Comment: good point. didn't notice it..